# class not being toggled on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have a navigation control containing links.

When a user clicks on a link, I want to toggle the class attribute of two links.

I want to assign a class of 'targeted' to the clicked link.

I also want to remove the 'targeted' class from the prior selected link.

here is my current es6 js.

```js
$(() => {
//when one is clicked, remove the class from each of them and then add the class to the one that was clicked
    $(document).on("click", ".tools-cover .tools-container > .row > .col-xs-12 > nav ul li a", (e) => {

        $(document).find(".tools-cover .tools-container > .row > .col-xs-12 > nav ul li a").removeClass("targeted");

        $(this).toggleClass("targeted");

    });

//when the page has loaded, click the first nav link on the nav
    $(document).find(".tools-cover .tools-container > .row > .col-xs-12 > nav ul li:first-child a").click();
});
```

```html
<div class="tools-cover">
  <div class="container tools-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Feeds</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Wearisma links</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share the html code as well

Comment: thats it in the post now.

Comment: I'm afraid 'this' keyword in arrow function is different.. not the element you expect

Comment: Try e.currentTarget

Comment: How did you learn about arrow functions but didn't learn how `this` works with them? This seems to happen quite often and I'm wondering why / how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) don't have their own `this`, so jQuery cannot set it to the current element. You have to use a "normal" function as event handler, or use `e.target` or `e.currentTarget` (not sure how well this works with event delegation) instead of `this`.

See also [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)